# Error in ts(ZOO) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I ran this code yesterday, and it executed perfectly. But today when I run it I experience errors. And when I check the ZOO table, it has no data, i is empty. Where could be the problem?

```
***library(Quandl)
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library(readr)
getSymbols("FB", from = '2018-02-01',
           to = '2018-12-30',warnings = FALSE,
           auto.assign = TRUE)
fb_data <- FB
ZOO <- zoo(fb_data$FB.close, order.by=as.Date(as.character(fb_data$date), format='%Y-%m-%d'))
fb_ts <- ts(ZOO)***
```

Answer (score 0):

The column name is `FB.Close` with a capital C, not lower case c, and it is already xts/zoo.  We can use quantmod's `Cl` function to pick out the close.  Note that `x` is an xts/zoo object.

```
x <- Cl(FB)
class(x)
## [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

If the purpose of the code in the question was to make it just a zoo object and not xts then specify that in `getSymbols` using `return.class="zoo"`:

```
# FB will be a zoo object
getSymbols("FB", from = '2018-02-01',
       to = '2018-12-30', warnings = FALSE,
       auto.assign = TRUE, return.class = "zoo")
```

or if you already have an xts/zoo object `x` it can be converted to just zoo using

```
# if x is xts/zoo object then z will be zoo object
z <- as.zoo(x)
```